# QToolBar position (How to make it stay at a fixed position)

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qtoolbar

I initially needed to display two QToolBars in such a way, they are in two rows. I found the solution for that problem through this:

[How to set the line where a QToolBar is displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441143/how-to-set-the-line-where-a-qtoolbar-is-displayed)

In my program there are a few QToolBars in the first row, they can be moved. In the second row I have another QToolBar which can't be moved (fixed).

My requirement is to make the 2nd QToolbar stay always at the bottom row. As of now, if the top QtoolBars are moved, 2nd toolbar position changes accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried setting the `QToolBar` to not movable? i.e.

```
mySecondToolBar->setMovable( false );
```

By default all `QToolBar` objects are movable. Although I'm not sure if this solution helps in the case of having two `QToolBar` stacked but worth a try.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtoolbar.html